# How to set default paper size in Edge browser?

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, microsoft-edge

We are using Microsoft Edge browser `(Edge Chromium, Version 91.0.864.41 (Official build) (64-bit))` to print receipts from an online ERP system.

We want the printer (an [OKI 411dn](https://www.cnet.com/products/oki-b411dn-printer-monochrome-led-series/)) to print A6 by default but we can't get it to work. The printer natively supports A6, but the edge dialogue does not show A6 in the print dialogue dropdown.

Now, according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#printingpapersizedefault you can set a default paper size, using the `PrintingPaperSizeDefault` registry key. So we tried to a custom value that fits the A6 size, like so:

[image: via regedit]

Viewing that value in Edge via [edge://policy/](http://edge://policy/) looks like this:

[image: via edge://policy/]

However, when we check Print dialogue in Edge browser, we cannot see the `custom` paper size anywhere:

[image: print dialogue Microsoft Edge]

We have restarted the machine, installed latest drivers, tried 'Print to PDF' etc.
Also checking Print Server Properties in Windows 10 gives us the following (notice A6 is there plus a bunch of other forms). What are we doing wrong??:

[image: Print Server Forms]

Comment: Are you actually using a printer server?

Comment: No, but that is what Windows 10 gives me when I take the properties for the printer.

Comment: I have now learned the problem is that the wrong driver was installed - "OKI PCL6 Class Driver 2" instead of "OKI B411"

Comment: Are you sure?  Cause it's odd the name of the printer is "Printer Server";  The name of the printer typically would be something like `OKI 411dn` instead of "Printer Server".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doooh, was using the wrong printer driver:
`OKI PCL6 Class Driver 2` instead of `OKI B411`.

Using the correct drivers shows A6 as an option in the printer dialogue dropdown box.